# Cell reference for each smallest value and offsetting to get the value in the adjacent column

Tags: excel

I have a list of temperatures and I need to list the smallest value in the array and then record the associated serial number in the column to the left. The issue I am having is that the numbers can occasionally be the exact same number so there are multiple smallest values that need to be recorded.

[image]

I have used the following to get the smallest value in the array;

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(D4,$D$4:$I$150,3,FALSE)="YES","",ROUND(SMALL($E$4:$E$102,C4),1)),"")
```

I have used the following to get the serial number for that temperature;

```
=IFERROR(CELL("contents",INDEX($D$4:$D$102,MATCH(IFERROR(SMALL($E$4:$E$102,C4),""),$E$4:$E$102,0))),"")
```

I have then attempted to get the next smallest value by using this in the cell below (which works);

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(D5,$D$4:$I$150,6,FALSE)="YES","",IF(ROUND(SMALL($E$4:$E$102,C5),1)=M$4,ROUND(SMALL($E$4:$E$102,C5),1),"")),"")
```

However, when it comes to getting the serial number associated with each of the duplicates I cannot think of a way to relate the two together.

I was wondering if there was a way of getting the cell reference for each instance of the small function and then offseting the column? To do this I attempted to use the Cell function coupled with the aggregate function but I just get an error so I dont think it is possible in this way.

Does anyone have any suggestions of an alternative way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one has the Dynamic Array formula FILTER(), put this in L4:

```
=FILTER(D:E,E:E=MIN(E:E))
```

IF not:

Put this in L4 and copy over and down

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($E$4:$E$102)/(($E$4:$E$102<>"")*($E$4:$E$102=MIN($E$4:$E$102))),ROW($ZZ1))),"")
```

Comment: I do not have this function :(